# Writing CSV infile changes to a CSV outfile using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I wrote the following code:

```
import sys, csv, operator
data = csv.reader(open('books.csv'),delimiter=',')
header = next(data)
print (header)
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
with open("books_sort.csv", "wb") as f:
#          fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
           fileWriter = csv.writer(f)
#           fileWriter.writerows(header)
#           fileWriter.writerows(sortedlist)

           for row in sortedlist:
              print (row)
#             f.writerows(row)
```

The objective of this code is to take a file with contents in columns and alphabetize the file based on the second column only. It then outputs the desired result in a new file. My code above can print the desired result but when I try to make it output a new file containing it, it does not work. You can see above in the comments for the parts where I tried to write a new file. Do guys have any ideas on how to do this? Before any of you say that an easier way would be to use pandas, I am specifically not allowed to do so. The following is the contents of my file:

```
Title,            Author,        Publisher,  Year,  ISBN-10,   ISBN-13
Automate the...,  Al Sweigart,   No Sta...,  2015,  15932...,  978-15932...
Dive into Py...,  Mark Pilgr..., Apress,     2009,  14302...,  978-14302...
"Python Cook...,  "David Bea..., O'Reil...,  2013,  14493...,  978-14493...
Think Python...,  Allen B. D..., O'Reil...,  2015,  14919...,  978-14919...
"Fluent Pyth...,  Luciano Ra..., O'Reil...,  2015,  14919...,  978-14919...
```

Comment: *Does not work* means nothing for me. You should say exactly what happens, errors (then give stacktrace), unexpected result (then give actual and expected result, flames everywhere (sorry I can nothing for you, call the fire department)...

Comment: ... Anyway, the csv module doc is explicit about that: open mode `"wb"` was for Python2, in Python 3 it must be opened in *text* mode, no implicit end of line. So I would expect `with open("books_sort.csv", "w", newline='') as f:` to behave better.

Comment: I highly suspect that's not the actual contents of the input file. Please [edit] your question and correct this. The best way to do it would be to open the file in a text editor, select its entire contents, and the paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making this harder than necessary.  First, let's clean up the example data as the unmatched double quotes confuse the `cvs.reader`:

```
Title,Author,Publisher,Year,ISBN-10,ISBN-13
Automate the...,Al Sweigart,No Sta...,2015,15932...,978-15932...
Dive into Py...,Mark Pilgr...,Apress,2009,14302...,978-14302...
"Python Coo...",David Beaz...,O'Reil...,2013,14493...,978-14493...
Think Python...,Allen B. D...,O'Reil...,2015,14919..., 978-14919...
"Fluent Pyt...",Luciano Ra...,O'Reil...,2015,14919...,978-14919...
```

Next, let's buid up a program based on the cvs module documentation:

```
import csv
import operator

data = csv.reader(open('books.csv', newline=''), delimiter=',')

header = next(data)

sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))

with open("books_sorted.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:
    cvsWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    cvsWriter.writerow(header)

    cvsWriter.writerows(sortedlist)
```

Which generates an output file with content:

```
Title,Author,Publisher,Year,ISBN-10,ISBN-13
Automate the...,Al Sweigart,No Sta...,2015,15932...,978-15932...
Think Python...,Allen B. D...,O'Reil...,2015,14919..., 978-14919...
Python Coo...,David Beaz...,O'Reil...,2013,14493...,978-14493...
Fluent Pyt...,Luciano Ra...,O'Reil...,2015,14919...,978-14919...
Dive into Py...,Mark Pilgr...,Apress,2009,14302...,978-14302...
```

Lacks the double quotes, but hopefully correct.  In your commented out code, you called `writerows()` on a single row

```
#fileWriter.writerows(header)

for row in sortedlist:
              print (row)
#             f.writerows(row)
```

Which we shouldn't expect to work.  Here you would use `writerow()` instead.

Comment: When I try to run youur version on the code from the command line, it says TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @user10200421, my belief is that you're running this under Python 2 despite your [python-3.x] tag above.  Run your Python with the -V flag at the command line to check the version.